# Typo in tag [anguarjs-digest-cycle]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Whilst browsing through tags, I noticed that [anguarjs-digest-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anguarjs-digest-cycle) is spelt incorrectly (missing the `l` in Angular). There is already [angular-digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-digest) which seems to be the correct tag to use (but I have no experience with Angular so could be wrong).

Comment: The rename is done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-digest-cycle

Comment: angular-digest also appears to be about AngularJS instead of Angular, so it's named incorrectly as well.

Comment: @BhargavRao Do you mind adding the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag?

Comment: I suspect Bhargav has held off on marking this complete because we may *also* want to do an additional merge into the [angular-digest] tag, as suggested in the question, @JL2210. We just need some Angular gastroenterologists to weigh in on how the digestive system works and what tag merges are appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular does not have a thing they call a "digest cycle". It has [change detection](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) which has little in common with AngularJS's digest cycle, except that they are both used for detecting changes.

Thus, in my opinion, [angular-digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-digest) should be renamed to [angularjs-digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-digest) and merged with the (now correctly spelled) [angularjs-digest-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-digest-cycle).

I've [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23223570) to the [angular-changedetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-changedetection) tag. This is what most people appear to be asking about when they use the [angular-digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-digest) tag along with [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular). Note that there is also an [angular2-changedetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-changedetection) tag out there that likely should be synonymized.

Notes on problematic questions:

- [Angular UpgradeModule $rootScope.$digest error, even though we are not triggering a digest manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46436306/215552) is a question about upgrading from [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) to [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and therefore it's appropriate to have both tags.
- Edited [Angular Promise does not run a digest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44357372/215552) to [AngularJS Promise does not run a digest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44357372/215552) and changed the tag to [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).
- [Angular Strap Tooltip Container Set to Directive Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37464490/215552) had neither [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) nor [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs); I added [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).
- Edited [Updating ng-charts barchart datasets in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44798189/215552) to use the [angular-changedetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-changedetection) tag.
- I'm not entirely sure what to do with [Angular binding to function results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41550175/215552) since it specifically asks about the digest cycle. I think it would actually be appropriate for it to have both [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [angularjs-digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-digest), since it is about both.

Comment: @BhargavRao Added some notes.

Comment: Completed as per this